# Initiate file download with Koa

Tags: node.js, download, koa

I'm using Koa as a webserver to serve my Polymer application. Upon pressing a button in the frontend `localhost:3000/export` is called. I would like to deliver a file-download to the client after packing the some files to a zip-archive.

**How to do this in Koa.js?**

*Here's an example on how to do it in Express (another option would be the [download-helper](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.download)*

```
app.get('/export', function(req, res){

  var path = require('path');
  var mime = require('mime');

  var file = __dirname + '/upload-folder/dramaticpenguin.MOV';

  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
router.post('/export', function*(){
  yield download(this, __dirname + '/test.zip')
})
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be able to simple set `this.body` to the file stream

```
this.body = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test.zip');
```

then set the response headers as appropriate.

```
this.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
this.set('Content-type', mimetype);
```

Comment: It's recommended to set the headers before the body.

Answer (score 27):

For anyone else who sees this in the future, it's worth mentioning that there is a built in `attachment` method on the `response` object that you can use to set the `Content-Disposition` to `attachment` with a specified filename. So you can do this:

```
this.attachment('hello.txt')
```

And it would be the same thing as the following:

```
this.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=hello.txt')
```

---

For Koa 2:

```
ctx.attachment('hello.txt')
```

Answer (score 3):

Browser default behaviour is to display the file, not to download it. To enforce download you need to do this:

```
this.header("Content-Type", "application/force-download")
this.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a different file download example with error checking, using Node with Koa 2. I am not sure if it is necessary to destroy the stream afterwards as described here  https://github.com/jshttp/content-disposition#options

```
router.get('/downloads/:version/:file', async function(ctx) {
  const fileName = `${__dirname}/downloads/${ctx.params.version}/${ctx.params.file}`;
  try {
    if (fs.existsSync(fileName)) {
      ctx.body = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
      ctx.attachment(fileName);
    } else {
      ctx.throw(400, "Requested file not found on server");
    }
  } catch(error) {
    ctx.throw(500, error);
  }  
});
```

In browser sample: https://myserver.com/downloads/1.0.0/CoolAppFile.zip